# Crashes for different reasons, every 20 minutes or so

Tags: windows-8, crash, bsod

This afternoon, my computer crashed (BSOD) 6 times in about 4 hours.

The strange thing is, each time, it gave a different reason:

1. `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`
2. `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`
3. `NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM`
4. `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXTENSION`
5. `KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`
6. `CACHE_MANAGER`

The first and second were the same.

I Googled around and found the various probable causes for the different messages. The most common suspect is an outdated driver, but there are many other possibilities.

Does anyone with a trained eye see a pattern here that could indicate some specific issue that my computer might have? I can't put all these pieces together.

I'm running Windows 8 on an HP Envy dv6.

Comment: Are you running Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1 there is a huge difference.  How quickly do these BSOD crashes happen?  Have you used a tool like Blue Screen Viewer to determine which drivers might be at fault?  Have you ran the SFC and DISM tools to verify your installation isn't corrupt.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using Windows 8.1. I haven't used any of those tools but I will check them out now

Comment: @Ramhound Can you confirm that this is the BlueScreen Viewer app you are referring to? http://download.cnet.com/BlueScreenView/3000-2094_4-10965136.html

Comment: You can use any tool you want that's the tool I use.  I take no responsibility nor do I want to verify anything on cnet for personal reasons

Comment: BlueScreenView is **CRAP**! Use Windbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: What's the [exact laptop model](http://bit.ly/1pDUL5C)? The error codes are not enough. For example, `NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM` could be misleading in this case because Windows crashed many times in a row, and that could lead to file system corruption. Open a command prompt as administrator, and run this command to check the file system health: `chkdsk %systemdrive% /r` Since it's the system drive, you'll need to schedule it, and then the actual check will run next time you restart Windows. When done, open another command prompt as admin, and run this to check system files, too: `sfc /scannow`